# laravel 5.4 register after payment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am working on an application where users can register after payment, below is my create method in `RegisterController`

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    
    $payment = $this->MakePayment($data);
    
    if($payment->error)
    {
        flash($payment->error, 'error')->important();
        redirect()->route('register');
    }
    else
    {
        //create user and return it
        return $user;
    }
}
```

but I get exception  instead of returning back

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError
>
> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in /home/tariqmahmood/www/local.referralfactorypro.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 35

Also, I have tried exit() after the redirect, it takes back to register route but an empty screen. Can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$authUser = //create user into db (i.e user::insert('userData'))
Auth::login($authUser, true);
return redirect('youtRedirectUrl');
```